# Schmitt-Trigger with Simulink

Tags: schmitt-trigger

I have a problem with simulating a Schmitt-Trigger and analyze it with MATLAB. I can do this with MultiSim or Proteus but for more advanced analysis I need to do this in Simulink.

In Library Browser under SimScape, there is a Foundation Library and "Electrical" inside it. There is no problem until here.

But when i take an op-amp and couple of resistors, I can not create a simple Schmitt-Trigger circuit. I mean there is not any junctions for supplying opamp.[image: Take a look at this]

I'm really new at using Simulink and searched over google and here but can not find any solutions. 
And another problem how can I measure the output voltage and plot it to see classical Schmitt-Trigger response?

Answer (score 1):

An op-amp isn't a schmitt trigger. If you don't have a schmitt trigger in your set of models, you can model one using an op-amp, but you need positive feedback (output sent to input) to make that work.

See this for ways to do so:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger#Op-amp_implementations

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that but I found this circuit for schmitt trigger applications. Tried it in multisim and proteus. It worked. I think I need to learn more about schmitt trigger. Thanks anyway